# Android SQLiteException on this.getReadableDatabase and this.getWritableDatabase()

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
    package com.myandroidapp.app.util;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "px.db";

        private static final String TABLE_IDENTITY = "identity";
        private static final String TABLE_DEFAULT_IDENTITY = "default_identity";

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onCreate");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.e("TAG", "upGrade");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.e("TAG", "downGrade");
        }

        public Cursor getIdentityCard() {

            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_IDENTITY;
            return queryDb(query);

        }

        public Cursor getDefaultIdentityCard() {

            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DEFAULT_IDENTITY;
            return queryDb(query);

        }

        private Cursor queryDb(String query) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); /*Error Comes here even if i use this.getWritableDatabase();*/
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return cursor;
        }

    }
```

### LOGCAT

```
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 8 to 5: /data/data/com.paytronix.client.android.app.marketplacegrill/databases/px.db
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:199)
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325):     at com.paytronix.client.android.app.marketplacegrill.util.DatabaseHandler.queryDb(DatabaseHandler.java:51)
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325):     at com.paytronix.client.android.app.marketplacegrill.util.DatabaseHandler.getIdentityCard(DatabaseHandler.java:39)
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325):     at com.paytronix.client.android.app.activity.Main$1.run(Main.java:26)
04-28 11:13:32.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1325):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

### Problem

I am getting Android `SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE when calling this.getWritableDatabase()` and  `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 8 to 5 when calling this.getReadableDatabase()`

**Scenario** : I have rooted my phone version `2.3.6 GalaxyS2` and got the `DB` file from an existing app and pushed it to my app's databases folder, so while accessing the `pushed DB` file I am getting the same error no matter what `DATABASE_VERSION` I use in my `SQLiteOpenHelper class`;

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace from logcat. Also you need something in your database helper `onCreate()` but that doesn't explain your problem the way you've explained it so far.

Comment: @laalto please check now

Comment: have you given this permission....<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @GVSharma its working now,but i haven't done any changes..not even added the permission,STRANGE???

Comment: that is what permission statements does..any way go ahead
keep coding

Answer (score 0):

Note that whenever you change your DB version that time you have to recreate your DB.

For that first you need to delete your DB from Database folder then again recreate your DB.

Please this code

```
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // Drop older table if existed
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "Your table name");

  // Create tables again
  onCreate(db);
 }
```

Hope this helps you!!
if its not working please let me know i will try to help you more.

Comment: I know its strange,but its working now without any change..don't know HOW?anyways if the issues comes again i'll post here.